# Moderator "Move comments to chat" failing

Tags: bug, comments, chat, moderator-tools

Moderators get auto-flags on extended comment discussions with an option to move the comments to chat when needed.  I moved several discussions in the past few hours, but the latest [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28070405/426671) is failing to move.

My first attempt threw a helpful message

> An error has occurred.

Now, if I try to migrate the comments, it just hangs - no message, nothing.

Please fix this.

Comment: Helpful messages are the best kind.

Comment: @ryanyuyu at least it was displayed in a red message box.

Comment: Proposal for a more informative message: *Something went horribly wrong.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69327/discussion-on-question-by-bluefeet-moderator-move-comments-to-chat-failing).

Comment: I had a similar issue today. However, I did receive a nice red message box stating something similar to "Sorry Dave, I can't do that" A check of http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people&host=askubuntu.com shows the room was not created. Both the users in question [myself](http://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek?tab=profile) and [heynnema](http://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema)  have well over the required rep to chat. A subsequent attempt also failed. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 21):

Confirmed. [Chat room created](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/69319/discussion-on-answer-by-iharob-how-to-deal-with-function-exits-on-a-function-tha), but only a few messages moved - and no auto-generated comment left pointing to the room.

Works on *this question*, however: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284182/moderator-move-comments-to-chat-failing/284184#comment145813_284182

My suspicion is that the process choked when trying to copy the first message from [this user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4371276/dmg) - note how that link doesn't exactly work? Marking this as a chat bug.

---

Ok, balpha fixed that user's account and [comment copying completed!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/69330/discussion-on-answer-by-iharob-how-to-deal-with-function-exits-on-a-function-tha) I'm leaving this bug open as a reminder for someone to make the logic here a bit more robust, as balpha states that the current code is "sprinkled with differences" - which is more positive than "riddled with bugs", but still probably worth a look.

---

More notes for those encountering this: even when it fails, the system will often still create the chatroom and copy some or all of the messages - however, the UI won't report this. Subsequent attempts will then notice the chat room already exists and return immediately (again, failing to report exactly what's happening) leading to confusion regarding the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: I'm going to start using "sprinkled with differences" when describing things now. But I'm glad this was reproduced, and fixed for the time-being.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, on [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/is-there-any-noun-in-english-which-changes-the-first-letter-in-the-plural). Should I be patient or make a fuss?

Comment: I let balpha know, @KitFox

Comment: I'm having this problem on [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/47260/325).  Room created [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/24223) and the first six comments were moved, and then it failed on a comment from [this user](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/33374/edwin-lambregts).