# "move comments to chat" moves the comments but doesn't tell you

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, moderator-tools

Moderators have the ability to move comments on a post to chat.  Usually when this feature is utilized the system leaves a comment below the post in your name announcing this as well as showing a success popup.

Today however, when I attempted to move some [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717013/help-i-added-a-debain-repository-and-my-computer-got-screwed-up) to chat nothing happened. No comment was created. No success (or error) popup. I went to chat and was able to manually find the room and create my own comment, so the actual move *is* working, there's just no feedback any more.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: [It looks like we can *probably* blame balpha for this one :P](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248041/203389)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't actually move the comments to chat – this had been done previously by another moderator. And the server returned a response telling you just that; unfortunately it did so in a format that was different from what the client expected, and thus it never displayed this fact to you.

This is fixed in the next build.

Comment: Ah.. I was only investigating because another mod said it didn't work.. Guess I should have tried a new post after I confirmed the room was created. My bad.

Comment: No blame on you -- it was still a bug.